# How is every cyclic submodule of $\mathbb{Q_{Z}}$ is a small submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am trying to prove that Rad($\mathbb{Q_{Z}}$) = $\mathbb{Q_{Z}}$ by showing that every cyclic submodule of $\mathbb{Q_{Z}}$ is a small submodule.

I know that a submodule $A$ of $\mathbb{Q_{Z}}$ is small iff $A+X= \mathbb{Q_{Z}}$ for $X \leq \mathbb{Q_{Z}} \Rightarrow X=\mathbb{Q_{Z}}$. I am having difficulty proving that $q\mathbb{Z}$ is small in $\mathbb{Q_{Z}},  \forall q \in \mathbb{Q_{Z}}$.

I can assume that $q\mathbb{Z}$ is not small, but I am not entirely certain how to obtain a contradiction.

If I can, then it follows that $\mathbb{Q_{Z}} = \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q_{Z}}}q\mathbb{Z} =$ Rad($\mathbb{Q_{Z}}$). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's easy to reduce the problem to showing that $\mathbb{Z}$ is small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first notice that $\frac{a}{b}\mathbb{Z} + X = \mathbb{Q_{Z}} \Leftrightarrow a\mathbb{Z} + X = \mathbb{Q_{Z}}$ for some right submodule $X$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. As $a\mathbb{Z} $ does not contain any rational numbers, there must exist $\frac{r}{s} \in X$ for some $r,s \in \mathbb{Z} , s\neq 0$.

Then $\frac{1}{r} \in \mathbb{Q}$ is  written as $\frac{1}{r}=an+x$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x \in X$. Then $1=r(an)+rx \in X$, as $r(an),rx \in X$. Thus, $X=\mathbb{Q_{Z}}$, so $a\mathbb{Z} \ll \mathbb{Q_{Z}} \Rightarrow \frac{a}{b}\mathbb{Z} \ll \mathbb{Q_{Z}}$

Comment: How is $\frac12\Bbb Z\subseteq\Bbb Z$, for example?

Comment: @rschwieb Alas, you are correct. I will delete this post until I find the solution